# File iPhone Simulator wasn't found

Tags: applescript, ios-simulator

I'm working on the following AppleScript which work fine on my machine

```
tell application "iPhone Simulator" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "h" using {command down, shift down}
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "h" using {command down, shift down}

tell application "System Events"
  set _position to position of window 1 of process "iOS Simulator"
  set _size to size of window 1 of process "iOS Simulator"
  set _x to item 1 of _position
  set _y to item 2 of _position
  set _width to item 1 of _size
  set _height to item 2 of _size
  set _coord_x to (_x + _width / 2) as integer
  set _coord_y to (_y + _height / 2) as integer
  do shell script "cliclick c:" & _coord_x & "," & _coord_y
end tell
```

Unfortunately, when I execute that script on another machine, the first line throws the following error even though the iPhone Simulator is launched:

```
error "File iPhone Simulator wasn’t found." number -43 from current application
```

Both machines are running the same version of Xcode (6.1) and the same simulator (iPhone / iOS 7.1)

Any idea why the application iPhone Simulator is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now called "iOS Simulator" and not "iPhone Simulator".  I suggest you change the first line to:

```
tell application "iOS Simulator" to activate
```

Comment: Ok. Will try that and get back to you. Do you know when this change was introduced? Because it's working fine with `iPhone Simulator`on my mac with Xcode 6.1 but it's throwing the error on another machine that has pretty much the same settings.

Comment: The name was changed in Xcode 6.0.  If it is working on one of your systems with Xcode 6.1, I suspect that it's finding an older version somewhere.  You should check what is actually running.